# Send NodeJS child process stdout to Express response object

Tags: node.js, express, es6-promise, node-streams

I currently pipe the stdout of a child process to an (Express) `response` object like this:

```
try{
    let proc = spawn(exe, args);
    proc.stdout.pipe(response);
    let exitCode = await ending.completion(proc);
}
finally {
    // my own clean up goes here (e.g. releasing locks)
}
```

where `ending.completion` is defined as

```
async function(process){
    return new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
        let done = false;
        process.on('exit', (code, signal)=>{
            if(!done){
                done = true;
                if(code !== null){
                    resolve(code);
                } else {
                    reject(signal);
                }
            }
        });
        process.on('error', (err)=>{
            if(!done){
                done = true;
                reject(err);
            }
        });
    });
};
```

This generally works fine except for the fact that `proc` internally does a lot of waiting (on the download/transfer) before it can complete/return. I would prefer allowing it to dump its output into a buffer, which then trickles into the response object as the download proceeds. How can I introduce such a buffer?

(A second (and I think related) problem is that if the download is aborted client-side, `proc` never completes but keeps waiting on its stdout.)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like `exec` [method](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback) does exactly what you need.

> Spawns a shell then executes the command within that shell, buffering
> any generated output.

Use it instead of `spawn`. Note that unlike `spawn`, `exec` expects the whole command (with all the args) as a single string. Here is example from an officials documentation:

```
const util = require('util');
const exec = util.promisify(require('child_process').exec;

async function lsExample() {
  const { stdout, stderr } = await exec('ls');
  console.log('stdout:', stdout);
  console.error('stderr:', stderr);
}
lsExample();
```

Comment: The two problems I have with `exec` are (1) output size is limited (at least by default -- will check maximum) and I need 100's of MB, and (2) data transfer will start only after process is complete and output fully buffered. I rather want data transfer to start as soon as data is available.

Comment: He wants the output to stream from the child process into the request, so the memory footprint stays small.